# Protractor: Is it possible to check if an element doesn't contain certain text?

Tags: node.js, protractor, automated-tests, aurelia, e2e-testing

On the page that I am testing, a user can have a single currency or multiple currencies (i.e EUR and USD)the currency/currencies will appear in the same div at the top of the page. 
If a user has multiple currencies, a tab for each currency will appear further down the page, if a user has only one currency, no tabs will appear (as there is no need for the user to switch tabs).

I am able to test multi currency users by checking to see if the text contained in the header matches the text contained in the currencies tabs.

However, as no tabs appear for a single currency, I'm not sure how to test this.

For example, if I have only a 'EUR' currency, is there a way to do something like

```
if element(by.className("currencies"))contains 'EUR'
```

`&& doesn't contain 'USD' && doesn't contain 'GBP'`
    `expect element(by.className("tabs").toDisplay.toBeFalsy()`

This is the code for the page object file

```js
this.checkCurrency = function(currency) {
 var checkBalance = element(by.className("balances"));
 checkBalance.getText().then(function (text) {
   if (text.indexOf("GBP" && "EUR")>= 0) {
  expect(element.all(by.linkText("GBP")).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
   console.log("EUR GBP buyer");
   }
   else if (text.indexOf("GBP" && "USD")>= 0) {
  expect(element.all(by.linkText('USD')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
   console.log("USD GBP buyer");
   }
   else
   {
   console.log("false");
   }
   });
};
```

Comment: Does `expect(element(by.className("tabs").isDisplayed()).toEqual(false)` not work for you?

Comment: Thanks for reply. The problem is that I need to be able to check to  see if a <div> contains 'EUR' and 'USD'/'GBP' but I also need to check if it contains just 'EUR' and doesn't contain 'USD/GBP'. The above will work in theory but the If Else isn't able to distinguish if the <div> contains just 'EUR' or contains 'EUR' and another currency.

Comment: Hmm, like `if (text.indexOf("string") === -1)`? Alternatively, this whole thing could look cleaner if instead of doing `if (text.indexOf("EUR") >= 0 && text.indexOf("USD") == -1 && text.indexOf("GBP") == -1)` You instead use regex: `if (text.matches(\^EUR$\g) && text.matches(\^(?!.*(USD|GBP)).*$\g)`

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll try that out and see how I get on

Answer (score 0):

From your description I'm not quite sure where the failure is.  In general you want to keep this kind of logic out of your page object.  Your test should understand what state the page should be in and call different functions.  I know that's not always possible, but it works out so much better if you can. Here is some general condition advise that should help.

You can catch the success state and a failed state of a promise.  Most people use the pass function, but forget about the fail function.

```
promise.then(passFunction, failFunction)
```

You can use this in several different ways.  If you realize that almost everything in protractor is returning a promise.
Example:

```
element(by.className("currencies")).getText()
.then(
function(text) {
  //check on something
},function(error){
  //don't check on something
  if(someCondition) {
    throw error;
  } else {
    //the test continues
  }
});
```

You can even do it with and expect

```
expect(element(by.className("currencies")).getText()).not.toContain("EUR")
.then(
function(passed) {
  //check on something
},function(failed){
  //don't check on something
  if(someCondition) {
    throw failed;
  } else {
    //the test continues
  }
});
```

Or a simple findElement

```
element(by.className("currencies"))
.then(
function(element) {
  //check on something
},function(error){
  //don't check on something
  if(someCondition) {
    throw failed;
  } else {
    //the test continues
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, my If Else statement would have about 6 or 7 different scenarios to test, using the above you posted, which would suit this best. I'm new to protractor and while I appreciate your above post, I'm a small bit confused as to how I would implement it.